# white-space no funciona con CSS GRID

Tags: css, css-grid-layout

Actualmente estoy probando CSS GRID y trabajo con las unidades de fracción FR, pero me produce un error.

Al principio no pasaba nada, porque estaba usando unidades de porcentaje y no me genera ningún error, lo que pasa acá, es que al ser unidades de porcentaje, el **grid-gap** no me funciona como debería funcionar.

Lo que hago es lo siguiente:

Tengo un **main-content** que tiene:

```
.main-content{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 4fr 2fr 2fr;
}
```

Lo que me produce lo siguiente: Tres columnas => 4fr 2fr 2fr

[image: CSS GRID]

Hasta el momento, esta todo mas que bien, pero fijense en la siguiente lista:

[image: CSS GRID]

Esta lista, así como la que esta encima y la que esta al costado, tienen las propiedades para hacer que el texto quiebre por decirlo de alguna manera y genere los tres puntos "..."

```
.element{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Lo que pasa, es que esto no funciona si uso unidades fr:

[image: CSS GRID]

Y si uso porcentajes, el problema esta en el **grid-gap**.

¿Alguno tiene una idea de como puedo hacer para que el texto se rompa así use unidades de fracción en CSS GRID?

Comment: Hola Axel, deberías editar la publicación para añadir un [mcve] y que podamos ver el problema directamente en la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a ponerle un width en píxeles, por ejemplo:

`width: 120px;`

La propiedad `white-space` solo reacciona si tiene un width definido.

Comment: Excelente, ojo el `with` debe ser especificado al contenedor principal